# angular-redux/store - @select Observables & stubs being shared between unit tests in same spec file

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, redux, angular-cli

I have a project created through Angular CLI, and it is using redux through the [angular-redux/store](https://github.com/angular-redux/store) library. When writing unit tests for components connected to the redux state, I am noticing an odd behavior. It seems like the first test in the spec file is creating observables and any subsequent test after the first use the same observables and cannot be cleared out. This causes a few issues:

- If the first test **does not** stub the selector out, any subscription to the observable in subsequent tests never complete/emit a value. This results in a Jasmine async timeout.
- If the first test **does** stub the selector, than that stub is used for all subsequent tests, and cannot be overwritten. But the subscriptions will emit a value at this point.

Here is my code for the **component**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { select } from '@angular-redux/store';
import memberSelectors from './member-search.selectors';

    @Component({
  selector: 'app-member-summary-container',
  template: `<app-member-summary [subscriber]="(subscriber$ | async)"></app-member-summary>`
})
export class MemberSummaryContainer {
  @select(memberSelectors.getSelectedMemberDetails) readonly subscriber$: Observable<any>;
}
```

Here is the code for my unit tests:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockNgRedux, NgReduxTestingModule } from '@angular-redux/store/testing';

import { MemberSummaryContainer } from './member-summary.container';
import { IMember } from './member-search.reducer';
import memberSearchSelectors from './member-search.selectors';

describe('MemberSummaryContainer', () => {
  let component: MemberSummaryContainer;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MemberSummaryContainer>;

  const subscriber: IMember = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MemberSummaryContainer ],
      imports: [NgReduxTestingModule],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    MockNgRedux.reset();
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MemberSummaryContainer);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should get the selected member from state', done => {
    const memberStub = MockNgRedux.getSelectorStub(memberSearchSelectors.getSelectedMemberDetails);
    memberStub.next(subscriber);
    memberStub.complete();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MemberSummaryContainer);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.subscriber$.subscribe(
      actualSequence => { expect(actualSequence).toEqual(subscriber); },
      null,
      done
    );
  });
});
```

The selector, getSelectedMemberDetails, is a simple selector so there isn't any crazy logic in there to cause any issues.

So the question is, what am I doing wrong? I've tried to mimic what is being done in angular-redux/store's example app, but something isn't working as expected.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi there, I asked a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137185/testing-component-template-with-angular-and-redux . Did you, by any chance, found out a solution to the strange MockNgRedux behaviour  ? thx